# What JavaFX data structure should I use in the following example?

Tags: java, data-structures, javafx

I have the following class `GroupStudentsBySurname` and it contains the following data structure `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Student>>`. 
Each `Student` object contains two attributes: `surname` and `english_score`

The keys are the surname of students taken from the Student object `Student.surname`. For a particular key `Lee`, it has an `ArrayList<Student>` where the Students share the same **surname**.

One of the method of this `GroupStudentsBySurname` class is to compute the `average_english_score` for Students having the same surname.

I would use a `TableView` data structure for the class `GroupStudentsBySurname`, which looks like the following:

```
 Surname |  average_english_score    <- column headings
    Lee  |      65
   Chan  |      86
   Smith |      76
```

I want to be able to use **track the changes** of class `GroupStudentsBySurname` every time I ***add/delete*** a `Student` object from the arraylist, which in turn affects the `average_english_score` attribute.

**Question:** I do not know what data structure from **javafx** I should use in this case? Would I need to use `ObservableMap` or `ObservableList` to **track the changes** whenever I **add / delete** a `Student` object.

Comment: It seems you already have a data structure.  Maslor gave an answer suggesting UI components for displaying the data structure.  Is that what you want?  Or were you interested in information on how to reflect your existing data structure using JavaFX specific data structures and idioms like ObservableList, ObservableMap and bindings.  Overall, this question is quite unclear to me, you probably need to edit it to clarify what your question is.  Also, [Java 8 lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) provide facilities to support your functionality.

Comment: @jewelsea  Sorry, I was not clear about my question earlier. Please see updates.

Answer (score 3):

JavaFX is a UI technology, so not entirely sure what you mean be 'data structure from JavaFX'.

Anyway, let's start with the data model (we'll get to the UI later).

First I think you need to introduce another class (which requires a valid implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` on `Student`):

```
public class StudentGroup
{
  private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
  private BigDecimal englishTotal = BigDecimal.ZERO;

  public BigDecimal getEnglishAverage()
  {
    return englishTotal.divide(students.size());
  }

  public Collection<Student> getStudents()
  {
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(students);
  }

  public void addStudent(Student student)
  {
    if (students.add(student))
    {
      englishTotal.add(student.getEnglishScore());
    }
  }

  public void removeStudent(Student student)
  {
    if (students.remove(student))
    {
      englishTotal.subtract(student.getEnglishScore());
    }
  }
}
```

Your class `GroupStudentsBySurname` then becomes:

```
public class GroupStudentsBySurname
{
  private Map<String, StudentGroup> students = new HashMap<>();

  ...
}
```

Then create an *adapter* row class, which will allow `StudentGroup` to be used in more grouping scenarios than just being grouped by surname and is what will be used with JavaFX:

```
public class StudentBySurnameRow
{
  private SimpleStringProperty surname;
  private SimpleStringProperty groupSize;
  private SimpleStringProperty englishAverage;

  public StudentBySurnameRow(String surname, StudentGroup studentGroup)
  {
    this.surname = new SimpleStringProperty(surname);
    this.groupSize = new SimpleStringProperty(Integer.toString(studentGroup.getStudents().size()));
    this.englishAverage = new SimpleStringProperty(studentGroup.getEnglishAverage().toString());
  }

  ...
}
```

Once you have these classes they can be slotted into a JavaFX `TableView` as per the [Oracle TableView tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) where you would create an `ObservableList` like this:

```
List<StudentBySurnameRow> studentBySurnameRows = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, StudentGroup> entry : groupStudentsBySurname.getStudents().entrySet())
{
  studentBySurnameRows.add(new StudentBySurnameRow(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}

table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(studentBySurnameRows));
```

Comment: I want to ask why there needs to be 2 classes: `StudentGroup` and `GroupStudentsBySurname`. It seems like they both do the same job in this case. What is the difference between two classes ?

Comment: I can't see the code for `GroupStudentsBySurname` but assumed it contains the logic that *groups* the `Student`s creating the `StudentGroup`s

Answer (score 1):

I would use either a [ListView](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) or a [TableView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html). In your case, if you just want to be able to manipulate the list, the first would be more practical. Otherwise, if you really want to use the whole map, the latter.